# post variable with textarea

Tags: forms, post

I think that if you assign a name attribute to an input type='text' that name becomes the post variable. How can you assign a post variable to am html textarea.  i cant seem to get it working.  Im just trying to take a user's imputed text from the textarea and put it into a mysql database.  thanks

form:

```
<form action='index.php' method='POST'>
<textarea name='form'></textarea>
</form>
<?php  $input=$_POST['form'];  ?>
```

Comment: You need a cgi script to get the variable
See this http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_TEXTAREA.html